# How much the hFE value decrease at -40C

Tags: transistors, bjt

We are using the BC856ALT1G in our products.
Below is the datasheet from ON Semiconductor.

[image]
[image]

How much does hFE decrease at -40C (low temperature)? How do I calculate the hFE value at low temperature?

Comment: It will drop a lot. Designing based on hfe is bad.

Comment: CMOS works better cold, BJT's work better hot.. So use CMOS OP AMP and/or MOSFET

Comment: my answer shud read -50%hFE minimum at -50'C unless saturated, then not significant, then use de facto Ic/Ib=10

Comment: I hope u got your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typical  relationship for a BJT , the lowly but still great PN2222A that costs less than a  penny.

[image]
[image]

## added

The temperature coefficient for Beta is called NTB and is given only in SPICE files by OEM

In every case I have seen so far including your device, it is a **positive temp coefficien**t. **Although @jonk has more data on this, I have yet to see evidence to the contrary.**

For more details https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-4/bjt-quirks/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59225/discussion-on-answer-by-tony-stewart-ee-since-75-how-much-the-hfe-value-decrea).

Answer (score 0):

If we have a look at the[Nexperia datasheet](http://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BC856_BC857_BC858.pdf) for their similar part number, we can get an idea of what is likely. Of course chances are better it might resemble the 'typical' curves if you specify the Nexperia part. Chances are also better if you operate near the middle of the curve in Ic.

[image]